# When are time changes of Feller-Dynkin processes still Feller-Dynkin processes?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

A Markov process $X_t$ on $E$ is a Feller-Dynkin (or sometimes just Feller) process if its semigroup is a strongly continuous, sub-Markov semigroup $\{P_t:t\geq 0\}$ of linear operators on $C_0(E)$ (my definition comes from the text of [Rogers and Williams](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1166383/?site_locale=en_GB) or see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller_process)).

I am wondering what is known about when a time change of a Feller-Dynkin process is still Feller-Dynkin.  I believe that I have read that this is not true in general (and can be a tricky thing to determine).  I would be curious to see an example where this fails and also to know if the Feller-Dynkin property is preserved if the time change is nice enough.

For what it's worth, the time changes I am interested in are actually $C^{\infty}$.  I do not need the Feller property to be preserved, but thinking about it made me realize I do not have a very good feeling for these sort of things.

Comment: By the so-called Dambis, Dubins-Schwarz theorem every continous local martingale is a time-changed Wiener process. Now it is enough to take your favourite martingale which is not a Markov process.

Comment: Piotr Miłoś: as you gave the answer in your comment, I would  recommend that you add an answer to this question so that Shawn can accept it. Best Regards

Comment: Yes, this sort of idea seems to be a useful source of counterexamples.

Answer (score 1):

If you time change $X_t$ using a "clock" of the form $B_t = \int_0^t b(X_s) ds$, with $b$ a bounded positive continuous function on the state space of $X_t$ that is also bounded below away from $0$, then the time-changed process will be a Feller process.  This follows directly from the Hille-Yosida theorem.

Comment: This is the type of thing I was looking for--now I'll try to convince myself I understand details. 